# Must declare the table variable "@".

Tags: c#

I tried copy data from DB1 to DB2.But I get error : Must declare the table variable "@TableName".

What is wrong this code ?

Function :

```
  public void TransferData()


    {
        SqlConnection source = new SqlConnection(strConnectDB1);
        SqlConnection destination = new SqlConnection(strConnectDB2);


        source.Open();
        destination.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM @TableName", source);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableName", listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        SqlBulkCopy bulkData = new SqlBulkCopy(destination);

        bulkData.DestinationTableName = listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        bulkData.WriteToServer(reader);

        .
        .


    }
```

Button :

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateTableName();

        TransferData();

    }
```

Comment: I don't think you can use a parameter as a table name like that.  Parameters are placeholders for data values, not object names.

Comment: @user..the variable you are adding is a table variable..that is why you are getting the error..

Comment: possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428684/dynamic-table-name-in-select-statement

Comment: @Yaugen that is a totally different issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The table name in a SQL `FROM` clause is not an expression, and therefore cannot be sent in a parameter.

You need to construct the SQL string manually, e.g.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", listbox1.SelectedItem), source);
```

I ***strongly*** recommend that you delimit the table name to prevent SQL injection attacks.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", "[" + listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace("]", "]]") + "]"), source);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't use @Parameter syntax for tables; best way how to do that is to close table name into [] and check if table name doesn't contain [] (sql injection precaution)

```
  if (listbox1.SelectedItem.Contains("[") 
     || listbox1.SelectedItem.Contains("]") {
     throw new Exception("Invalid table name");
  }

  SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand(string.Format(
    "SELECT * FROM [{0}]",listbox1.SelectedItem), source);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following; Replace your SqlCommand code to this

```
  SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), source);
```

And remove the line where you are adding the parameter. It should work like this. You cannot use @Parameter syntax for tables.

Comment: This is a SQL injection vulnerability.  At the very least database object names should be enclosed (using square brackets in SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

**May be you can try this:**

public void TransferData()

```
{

    string strTableName=string.empty;
    SqlConnection source = new SqlConnection(strConnectDB1);
    SqlConnection destination = new SqlConnection(strConnectDB2);


    source.Open();
    destination.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM"+strTableName, source);

    strTableName=listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


    SqlBulkCopy bulkData = new SqlBulkCopy(destination);

    bulkData.DestinationTableName = listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

    bulkData.WriteToServer(reader);

    .
    .


}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: This is a SQL injection vulnerability.  At the very least database object names should be enclosed (using square brackets in SQL Server).