# SQL Server Select from multiple tables in array

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Simple question about SQL Server 2808.

View1:

```
Select name from sys.tables where name like 'ab%'
```

Result:

```
Name
----
ab01
ab02
abxyz etc...
```

Now I want to query over those tables.

```
 Select * from view1
```

Of course I get ab01, ab02, abxyz. What I want is to query over the content

```
select * from ab01, ab02, abxyz
```

best of all would by to use union over the view1 query

Something like

```
Union view1
```

would be something like

```
Select * from ab01
union 
select * from ab02
....
```

any ideas?

Greets

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL for this, with `sp_executesql`.  You cannot put such queries into a view.

Comment: You can try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17429218/1627055

Comment: also `union` will only work if the table structure of all the tables are identical (or at least have the same amount of columns with identical order of datatypes)

Comment: Rewind: It works perfect, but how can get the result in a select statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a cursor. 
 Create a temporary table. 
 Loop through the cursor and add the results to the temporary table. 
 Select all from temporary table.