# BigQuery loop to select values from dynamic table_names registered in another table

Tags: sql, dynamic, google-bigquery, procedure, tablename

I'm looking for a solution to extract data from multiple tables and insert it into another table automatically running a single script. I need to query many tables, so I want to make a loop to select from those table's names dynamically.

I wonder if I could have a table with table names, and execute a loop like:

```
foreach(i in table_names)
    insert into aggregated_table select * from table_names[i]
end
```

Comment: If this link can help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428684/dynamic-table-name-in-select-statement

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset1.*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX IN (SELECT table_name FROM `project.dataset2.list`)
```

This approach will work if below conditions are met

- all to be processed table from list have exact same schema
- one of those tables is the most recent table - this table will [define schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#schema_used_for_query_evaluation) that will be used for all the rest tables in the list
- to meet above bullet  - ideally list should be hosted in another dataset

Obviously, you can add INSERT INTO ... to insert result into whatever destination is to be

Please note: Filters on _TABLE_SUFFIX that include subqueries cannot be used to limit the number of tables scanned for a wildcard table, so make sure your are using longest possible prefix - for example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset1.source_table_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX IN (SELECT table_name FROM `project.dataset2.list`)
```

So, again - even though you will select data from specific tables (set in `project.dataset2.list`) the cost will be for scanning all tables that match `project.dataset1.source_table_*` woldcard

While above is purely in BigQuery SQL - you can use any client of your choice to script exacly the logic you need - read table names from list table and then select and insert in loop - this option is simplest and most optimal I think

Comment: Thanks! This solution works under the conditions you mentioned. But tables I'm going to query are in different projects and different datasets. Projects and datasets have no patterns on their names. The only pattern is that all tables are in: `project.dataset.events_*` where "project" and "dataset" will be distinct for each iteration.

Comment: do you have another idea to make this work under my conditions?